# ReactJS: fakepath issue in repeater

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a repeater, so when user clicks on plus icon then a new row with two input tags is appended. Below is my code :
repeater.js

```
import React from "react"
const Details = (props) => {

  return (
    props.Desc !== '' ?
      props.Desc.map((val, idx) => {
        let desc = ` desc-${idx}`, file = `file-${idx}`
        return (
          <tr key={val.index}>
            <td> Description</td>
              <td >
                <input type="text" defaultValue={val.desc} name="desc" data-id={idx} id={desc} className="form-control " />
              </td>

            <td className="mr-2">  Files</td>
            <td>
              <input type="file" defaultValue={file} name="file" id={file} data-id={idx} className="form-control " />
            </td>
            <td>
              {
                idx === 0 ? <button onClick={() => props.add()} type="button" className="btn btn-primary text-center"><i className="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                  : <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={(() => props.delete(val))} ><i className="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
              }
            </td>
          </tr >
        )
      })
      : null
  )
}
export default Details
```

Details.js

```
import React, { Fragment, Component } from 'react'
import Details from './repeater.js'

class CreateDetail extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            inputList: [{ index: Math.random(), desc: "", file: "" }],
        }
    }

    onSubmit = (e) => {
        console.log('data : ', this.state.inputList[0]);
    }

     handleChange = (e) => {
         if (["desc", "file"].includes(e.target.name)) {
             let Desc = [...this.state.inputList]
             inputList[e.target.dataset.id][e.target.name] = e.target.value;
         } else {
             this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
         }
     }

    addNewRow = (e) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
    inputList: [...prevState.inputList, { index: Math.random(), desc: "", file: "" }],
       }));
    }

     deteteRow = (index) => {
        this.setState({
             inputList: this.state.inputList.filter((s, sindex) => index !== sindex),
         });
     }

    clickOnDelete(record) {
       this.setState({
          inputList: this.state.inputList.filter(r => r !== record)
      });
    }

    render() {
        let { inputList, flag } = this.state
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-sm-12">
                            <div className="card">
                                <div className="card-body">
                                    <form className="needs-validation" onChange={this.handleChange}>
           <div className="form-group row">
             <label className="col-xl-3 col-md-3">Details</label>
                 <div className="col-9 col-md-9">
                    <table className="table">
                        <tbody>
                          <Details add={this.addNewRow} delete={this.clickOnDelete.bind(this)} Desc ={inputList} />
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div className="pull-right">
                       <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.onSubmit}> save </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div >
                </div >
            </Fragment >
        )
    }
}

export default CreateDetail
```

But I am facing one issue, when I use the input tag's type "file" and I upload an image then I am receiving the **fakepath** as shown below.

```
C:\fakepath\6t8Zh249QiFmVnkQdCCtHK.jpg
```

I am encountering this problem **only in repeater**. If I use an input tag with type "file", outside the repeater then I am receiving the correct path.

The fake path is the main issue because if I extract the file name and upload it to s3 then empty image is uploaded to s3.
How can I upload a file in repeater?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the browser will not allow getting the local path of the file.you can use the data as form data and store it in state and can send it to S3.
like

```
      handleChange = (e) => {
             let formData = new FormData
for (var i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {
    formData.append(e.target.name, e.target.files[i])
}
             .....

         }
```

Comment: Thank you. I have used the form data and it has partially resolved the issue. I mean now I am receiving the file object instead of fake path. But in repeater when I add a new row and I upload another image then I am receiving only the first image's file object. But the submit should return all the uploaded images which is 2

Comment: check the code now. you can change the append file name by changing e.target.name. also e.target.files will contain the array of files you are selected